# Manual Download, and install Maven plugin

Tags: maven, plugins

So I downloaded This plugin

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/cobertura-maven-plugin/2.5

How do I get it manually installed to maven ?

I've tried

```
maven -DartifactId=cobertura-maven-plugin -DgroupId=org.codehaus.mojo -Dversion=2.5 plugin:download
```

But get this error:

```
[WARNING] Cannot resolve plugin-mapping metadata for groupId: org.codehaus.mojo:
cobertura-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:2.5 - IGNORING.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Required goal not found: plugin:download in org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-plugin-plugin:2.4.3
```

Comment: Have you resolved this? I need too add amven plugin from maven too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use this command to download plugins so it also download also all the required dependencies:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.6:get -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version
```

manually downloading plugins is asking for troubles and a lot of going back and forth to recover all the dependencies.

If you do not have the option, and must do it manually, use the command :

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.1:install-file ...
```

to install them.

see this page for the attributes available:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html

Comment: This just ended nearly an hour of frustration for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

IF the Jar can be searched from Maven Center Repository, you can just use this:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>
```

Others see the full doc: 
https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to execute that particular version of the plugin, you could do something like:

```
mvn org.codehaus.mojo:cobertura-maven-plugin:2.5:cobertura
```

Can't you simply define it in your pom.xml?